# What does "もんだなって" mean?

Tags: parsing

I'm reading a manga and I found that phrase. What is it supposed to mean?
Is it some kind of informal way to speak?

This is the full sentence:

男でもいけるもんだなって思ってさ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several things here.

- `もん` is colloquial for `もの`
- `だ` is the usual copula
- `な` here is the variation of `ね` usually used to imply wondering or wishfulness. Sometimes written as `なあ` or `なぁ`.
- `って` can be thought of as contraction of `と言う`, though it can mean other things as well.

So, without knowing the context (`いける` may mean several things), the whole phrase could be translated as:

"Being a guy is not too bad either, you know. That's what I think, anyway."

Comment: Well, that certainly is pretty complicated. Thanks a lot.

Can you elaborate a bit more on the "もの" part, though?
I don't really understand how it's used and its meaning in the sentence. Is it kinda "**the fact** of being a guy"?

Comment: It deserves its own question, but check out [this](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/11704/3295) answer.

Comment: P.S. actually now that I look at it, I think here it may actually be the noun `物` (=thing/concept/fact), and not the particle もの.

Comment: Even if it's もん? Can the noun 物 be contracted?

Comment: How could you translate that sentence without any context?  I could not at all.  It could mean too many completely different things.