# 《だなって》はどういう意味ですか

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 死 は門 だなって

the sentence is from 『入殓师』(おくりびと，Departures), and I don't know the structure and grammar meaning of "だ & なって" here.

Comment: Most probably the following answers your question. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13036/45489

Answer (score 1):

I searched 『入殓师』 and found whole sentence from [here](https://meigennavi.net/word/09/093263.htm).

Is following sentence correct?

> 長いこと、ここ（斎場）さいると、つくづく思うのよの。
> 死は門だなって。
> 死ぬってことは、終わりってことではなくて、そこをくぐり抜けて、次へ向かう、まさに門です。

## First

In this case, It's better to see more around sentences.

Important part for understanding is following.

> 長いこと、ここさいると、つくづく思うのよの。
> 死は門だなって。

It is **inverted sentence**.

## Split

It can be able to split as following. (omitted "、" and "。")

- "長いことここさいると"
- "つくづく思うのよの"
- "死は門だなって"

## Align

Result of aligned is following.

> 長いことここさいると、死は門だなってつくづく思うのよの。

## Made easy to translate

Sentences made easier to translate is following.

> 長い間ここにいると、死は門だなって思います。

## Why Inverted??

The character want to focus on "死は門だな".

Comment: Are 長いことここさいると and 思うのよの dialectal?

Comment: @Kaskade
ここさいる is dialectal.
よの cannot be determined.