# What is the meaning of もんな

Tags: slang, colloquial-language, parsing

Reading "プラチナデータ" by 東野圭吾.

Not clear on the meaning of:

> "俺、何度も彼女を殺しそうになった**もんな**" -
>
> "I often almost killed her ... (monna?)"

What is "monna"? I suppose "mono nara" ("if that thing"), but then I don't understand the whole sentence - is it "If I often almost killed her"?

Answer (score 4):

More than anything, it is a colloquial way of adding the nuance of "retrospective confession or boasting" in my own words.

Answer (score 3):

I think that it comes from the grammar form [～もの + だ](http://maggiesensei.com/2010/04/08/requested-lesson-%E3%80%8C%E3%82%82%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B%E3%80%8D%E3%80%8C%E3%82%82%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%80%8D%E3%80%8C%E3%81%A0%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A6%E3%80%8Dmonkamondadanante/). Which when changed to casual becomes もんだ which then you could add a な to.

ものです-> もんだ->もんだな->もんな

I think this may be a usage of 'reason/explanation' version of ～もの, perhaps in a sentence before or after the character is talking about why he had often almost killed her?

Comment: nope, the 丁寧語 of なったもんな is なりましたもんな, not なったものですな. This is a sentence ending particle, not a formal noun.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your comment is in reference to, but what I'm trying to explain is that the もんな from the poster's question comes from もの　and な.

I edited the question so hopefully that is more clear

Comment: It's correct that it comes from もの+な, but ものです is not relevant.

Comment: I apologize if it was confusing, I was only using the words 'ものです' as a reference to that grammar structure as explained in the link.  I've changed it to もの＋だ to make it even clearer.

Comment: @ishikun Let me try and see if I can get it right: a **formal noun** (形式名詞) is like a noun in form, so it can turn the clause before it into a relative clause and be followed by だ.  (As a formal noun, もの is a *nominalizer*.)  But since this is the **sentence final particle** (終助詞), it doesn't act like a noun, and you can't put だ after it any more than you can put だ after よね.  (Plus, it can come after だ, something no noun can do.)

Comment: (reminded me of this thread... http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11703/making-sense-of-%E3%82%82%E3%82%93)

Comment: @snailboat  Ahh I kind of get what you mean :D.  I'm still confused though, is it not the usage of ものだ　as in the second one on this [page](http://www.renshuu.org/index.php?page=grammar/individual&id=162)

Comment: @snailboat But actually [this usage](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2240/ending-sentence-with-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A0%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE-or-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE) right?

Comment: @ishikun. It is *not* the second usage on the first page you link to. もの in ものだ is a formal noun, here we are discussing a sentence final particle. Incidentally, I do not agree with that page that the use of ものだ is for a "reason, justification, or excuse", so I think they are also confusing the 2 usages. ものだ is explained here: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/thsrs/17282/m0u/

Answer (score 2):

It's a variation of entry 2イ here:

http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/219750/m0u/

As Goo says, it's basically an exclamatory way to state a reason for something, 「詠嘆の意をこめて理由を表す」. I don't have the context in this case, but I would say that in most cases the meaning is approximately the same as

> 俺、何度も彼女を殺しそうになったからな

and I would give the English translation as roughly

> I did almost kill her several times, didn't I...

Comment: Thanks for the replies! This sentence is uttered by a character being interrogated by the police, boasting about his "prowesses" with his 彼女 using a special device called a "電トリ
". I would probably go with "もんな" -> "からな", since the character is not offering any reason other than boasting he is really proud of himself...

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to "right ?"
Used by men
The equivalent used by women would be もんね

相手に自分の言ったことへの同意や、肯定を求める言い方です。
男性の言い方です。
女性であれば「〜もんね 」です。

Exemples

> 今日って寒いもんな。
> It's cold today, right ?

Source:
https://hinative.com/ja/questions/1911840

Comment: `相手に自分の言ったことへの同意や、肯定を求める言い方です。 男性の言い方です。 女性であれば「〜もんね 」です。` `今日って寒いもんな。` <- When you copy from another page, please always include the source, and clearly show which part of your answer is citation and which is your original.

Comment: Hi, you are right, I have thus updated the answer