# What is the exact nuance of じゃないもんな in this sentence?

Tags: nuances, reading-comprehension, negation

[image]

I understand the character is quite shocked by how big the 離れ is, however, I'm unsure of the actual nuance of the sentence.

離れって広さじゃないもんなあ。。。

Is he commenting it like "This is quite spacious for an 離れ, isn't it?" or is it more like "Things called 離れ aren't spacious"?

Comment: Have you tried to translate it literally? 広さじゃない is "This is not a size", and 離れって広さじゃない is "This is not the (typical) size of a 離れ".

Comment: If your doubt is what you put in the title, rather than what 離れって広さじゃない means, this seems related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13227/43676

Answer (score 1):

> "This is quite spacious for an 離れ, isn't it?"

This interpretation looks better.
離れ is an annex, which is used in contrast to 母屋(おもや) "main building (of mansion)". 離れ is thus a small building in general and based on this thought, the character feels "this is too spacious to be called 離れ".