# Can です be used attributively (as a modifier of a noun)?

Tags: copula, attributive

Goo dictionary lists the 連体形 (attributive) form of copula as [です](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/151501/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99/) but does not provide an example of an attributive usage. Can です be really used attributively? I have problems finding any example of it.

Comment: 「です」の連体形っていうと・・「～です+ので」とか？ 「～です+noun」って、なさそうですねぇ‥

Comment: Odd really that it can’t be used like that, since 〜ます+noun is fine in formal contexts.  I don’t think I’ve ever seen 〜であります+noun or 〜でございます+noun, but it feels like they should be possible to use in theory...

Comment: 「中村の弟でございます中村太郎と申します。」って大丈夫ですよね…？「です」にすると文が途中で終わる感じになっちゃいますよね…なんででしょう笑

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, I think it's because of the way that です is a sort of artificial construct that appeared relatively recently.  Although it grew out of でございます and/or であります, it functions differently, more specifically as a kind of 終止形 defective copula that imparts specific register information.  ("Defective" in part in that it is analyzable as only functioning as register and not as a copula in [形容詞]いです constructions; hence the invalidity of *[形容詞]いだ.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this page](https://www.kokugobunpou.com/%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99/), the attributive です connects to only ので and のに.

> 上の活用表で連体形の「です」が丸かっこで囲んであります。
>
> これは、連体形の「です」が用いられるのは、助詞の「ので」「のに」が付く場合だけにかぎられるということを意味しています。つまり、連体形であっても、体言（名詞）は付きません。「雨です日」という言い方はしませんね。

It's also possible to say ですこと and [ですもの](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2240/5010) at the end of a sentence, but this こと/もの is usually categorized as a sentence-end particle rather than a noun.

Comment: I must disagree with that page on one count -- the 連体形 **by definition** is the form that attaches to a 体言.  Since です never attaches to a 体言, **by definition**, it cannot be the 連体形.  である could be, but not です.  Considering also the historical development of です, it is kind of an artificial construct that functions a little differently than earlier であります, so this lack of a real 連体形 functionality is not all that surprising.  Trying to force です into the full verb-paradigm model is a mistake, in my opinion.

Comment: (To clarify: I have no argument with naruto's post, just with the linked https://www.kokugobunpou.com/助動詞/です/ page. :) )