# Translation of ないもの

Tags: translation

兄さんが私の相手をするはずなんてないもの。

I couldn't understand the above sentence properly, especially the **なんてないもの** part.

I have looked for the meaning of **相手をする** that can be translated as keep someone company or to take notice, and in my interpretation of the sentence would be "paying attention".

**ないもの** literally would be something that doesn't exist.

So, can I translate the sentence as follow:

"It would have been asking for the impossible for my brother to pay attention to me."

Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2240/ending-sentence-with-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%a0%e3%82%82%e3%81%ae-or-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%82%82%e3%81%ae

Comment: `ないもの literally would be something that doesn't exist.` ← Nope.　もの does not mean "thing" in this context.

Comment: Could it be もの in the sentence mean a person?

Comment: No.  Please read the linked Q&A.  もの is a sentence-ending particle in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 兄さんが私の相手をするはずなんてないもの。
>   There is no way my brother would pay attention to me, you know.

This is a combination of the following three grammar points:

- The はずがない sentence pattern

  - [Learn JLPT N4 Grammar はずがない](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AF%E3%81%9A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-hazu-ga-nai/)
- なんて that replaces が/を/etc

  - [Learn JLPT N3 Grammar なんか・なんて・など](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B-nanka-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A8-nante-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A9-nado/)
- もの as a sentence-end particle used to justify/explain something (often もん in informal speech)

  - [Learn JLPT N2 Grammar もの](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE-mono/)

So the simpler version of this sentence is 兄さんが私の相手をするはずがない. From this, が was replaced by なんか to add negative emotion, and もの was added to add the nuance of "you know" or "you see".

Comment: Thank you so much, I got a good lesson from you. なんて is really a tricky word, I never thought of はずがない since なんて was in between.