# って言ってるような in こんだけ集まってたら奪ってくれって言ってるようなもんでしょ

Tags: meaning

ロケット団 say this right after they catch all the フシギソウ in a net and try to take them away. The part that really confuses me is って言ってるような. I know the words but don't understand the sentence

> こんだけ集まってたら奪ってくれって言ってるようなもんでしょ

Comment: Related?: [What does 。。んだようなものだもんね mean in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82277/43676)

Answer (score 1):

It means:

"It's like you're saying 奪ってくれ"

In other words, "You're asking for it."